# Why does OpenGL seem to ignore my glBindTexture call?

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm having problems making a simple sprite rendering. I load 2 different textures. Then, I bind these textures and draw 2 squares, one with each texture. But only the texture of the first rendered object is drawn in both squares. Its like if I'd only use a texture or as if glBindTexture don't work properly. I know that GL is a state machine, but I think that you only need to change active texture with glBindTexture.

I load texture with this method:

```
 bool CTexture::generate( utils::CImageBuff* img )
 { 
  assert(img);
  m_image = img;
  CHECKGL(glGenTextures(1,&m_textureID));

  CHECKGL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,m_textureID));
  CHECKGL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR));
  CHECKGL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR));
  //CHECKGL(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,img->getBpp(),img->getWitdh(),img->getHeight(),0,img->getFormat(),GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,img->getImgData()));
  CHECKGL(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img->getWitdh(), img->getHeight(),
   0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img->getImgData()));

  return true;
 }
```

And I bind textures with this function:

```
void CTexture::bind()
 {
  CHECKGL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,m_textureID));
 }
```

Also, I draw sprites with this method

```
void CSprite2D::render()
 {
  CHECKGL(glLoadIdentity());
  CHECKGL(glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D));
  CHECKGL(glEnable(GL_BLEND));

  CHECKGL(glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA));
  m_texture->bind();

  CHECKGL(glPushMatrix());

  CHECKGL(glBegin(GL_QUADS));
  CHECKGL(glTexCoord2f(m_textureAreaStart.s,m_textureAreaStart.t)); // 0,0 by default
  CHECKGL(glVertex3i(m_position.x,m_position.y,0));

  CHECKGL(glTexCoord2f(m_textureAreaEnd.s,m_textureAreaStart.t)); // 1,0 by default
  CHECKGL(glVertex3i( m_position.x + m_dimensions.x, m_position.y, 0)); 

  CHECKGL(glTexCoord2f(m_textureAreaEnd.s, m_textureAreaEnd.t)); // 1,1 by default
  CHECKGL(glVertex3i( m_position.x + m_dimensions.x, m_position.y + m_dimensions.y, 0));  

  CHECKGL(glTexCoord2f(m_textureAreaStart.s, m_textureAreaEnd.t));  // 0,1 by default
  CHECKGL(glVertex3i( m_position.x, m_position.y + m_dimensions.y,0));

  CHECKGL(glPopMatrix());

  CHECKGL(glDisable(GL_BLEND));
 }
```

Edit:
I bring also the check error code:

```
int CheckGLError(const char *GLcall, const char *file, int line)
{
    GLenum errCode;

    //avoids infinite loop
    int errorCount = 0;
    while ( (errCode=glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR && ++errorCount < 3000)
    {
        utils::globalLogPtr log = utils::CGLogFactory::getLogInstance();
        const GLubyte *errString;
        errString = gluErrorString(errCode);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "In "<< __FILE__<<"("<< __LINE__<<") "<<"GL error with code: " << errCode<<" at file " << file << ", line " << line << " with message: " << errString << "\n"; 
        log->addMessage(ss.str(),ZEL_APPENDER_GL,utils::LOGLEVEL_ERROR);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format the post better, being sure to put code into blocks (shift code in by four spaces).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you are done sending vertex data to OpenGL, you need to call [glEnd](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBegin.xml), which I don't see called anywhere in your code. It should probably be before your PopMatrix call.

For example, [glBindTexture's documentation says](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindTexture.xml):

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glBindTexture is executed between the execution of glBegin and the corresponding execution of glEnd.

I assume your CHECKGL macro is supposed to catch reports via glGetError, in which case you might want to go back and make sure it works.

Comment: You are right! What stupid error!!! But CHECKGL didn't said nothing. It is very strange, because the code works fine, but no error is found...

Comment: I wouldn't expect glGetError to work between begin and end (or if you miss an end) you can easily wrap glBegin and glEnd yourself to catch this on a frame by frame basis. zero some value at start of frame, increment on a begin, decrement on an end and assert/trace/crash if its not zero when done rendering that frame to catch the error